# Quick-sort in ascending order

Tags: java, quicksort

I am trying to pass my implementation of the Quicksort through a tester; however, I get Array Index Out Of Bounds exception of -1 on the commended line

```
public void quickSort(ArrayList<String> data, int firstIndex,
                      int numberToSort) {
    if (data.size() < 16) {
        insertionSort(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);
    } else {
        int index = partition(data, firstIndex, numberToSort);

        if (firstIndex < index - 1)
            quickSort(data, firstIndex, index - 1);
        if (numberToSort > index)
            quickSort(data, index, numberToSort);
    }

}

@Override
public int partition(ArrayList<String> data, int firstIndex,
                     int numberToPartition) {
    String pivot = data.get(firstIndex);
    int left = data.indexOf(firstIndex);
    int right = data.indexOf(numberToPartition);

    while (left <= right) {
        while (data.get(left).compareTo(pivot) < 0) // this is where I get the error                           
            left++;

        while (data.get(right).compareTo(pivot) > 0)
            right--;

        if (left <= right) {
            temp = data.get(left);
            Collections.swap(data, left, right);
            data.set(right, temp);

            left++;
            right--;
        }
    }
    return left;
}
```

I have tried to debug my code but it seems that I just don't see a way to fix the error. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ```indexOf``` returns -1 if it can't find anything.

Comment: Evidently `left` is -1

Comment: It seems you're decreasing `right` until `right ==-1` and therefore `data.get(right)` throws `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1`

Comment: @MadMatts his error isn't on that line. It's on the line concerning `left`...

Answer (score 1):

Why in the world are you doing

> ```
> int left = data.indexOf(firstIndex);
> int right = data.indexOf(numberToPartition);
> ```

?  That looks for the the values of `firstIndex` and `numberToPartition` among the elements of the `List` being sorted.  Those values are by no means certain to be present in the data, and even if they are, it is entirely coincidental.  Their indices in the data are not meaningful.

In the event that one or both of those values is *not* present in the data, `indexOf()` returns `-1`, which you then happily pass to `List.get()`.

It looks like what you want is more like

```
 int left = firstIndex;
 int right = firstIndex + numberToPartition - 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `firstIndex` does really occur in `data`, if not the `.indexOf` method returns -1  and you will get an `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` at `int left = data.indexOf(firstIndex);`